# In XAML, specify an Icon from another assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

I'm new to WPF and XAML.  I have the following solution which WORKS using codebehind.  But it seems to me to be something that should be easier to specify in XAML.

I want to set the Icon to a resource in another assembly (specifically, so the "FlowDecisionIcon" in System.Activities.Presentation).  The following code works, when added to the constructor in the codebehind:

```cs
InitializeComponent(); // This was already there
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/System.Activities.Presentation;V4.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component/themes/icons.xaml") };
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
Icon = this.Resources["FlowDecisionIcon"] as DrawingBrush;
```

I was hoping there would be a nice way for me to specify this either in the XAML as something like:

```xml
<Window xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
Icon="sap:FlowDecisionIcon"> ...
```

Or, just specify it in Visual Studio in the Properties panel for the Icon property.  But I've been unsuccessful in figuring out the syntax to do either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're in a Window control.

```
<Window Icon="{DynamicReosurce FlowDecisionIcon}"
     .....
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ReosurceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/System.Activities.Presentation;V4.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component/themes/icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

But, it's advised to move the merging of the resources to the App.xaml file.

Comment: It is for a control that derives from System.Windows.Controls.Control.  I replaced "<Window.Resource>" with my parent control, and that part seems to work.  But on the first line, in VS I have a blue underline for "{DynamicResource FlowDecisionIcon}" that says: 'The resource "FlowDecisionIcon" could not be resolved.'

Comment: Usually, Visual Studio has a problem finding resources. When you run it, is the icon shown? If not, try to use `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicRsource` - if an Exception is thrown complaining that the resource couldn't be found - something is wrong with loading the resources. Post the source here, maybe I'll be able to help.